# How to pass null values to call procedure using native query?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I call a stored procedure using JPA native query and PostgreSQL DB.

@Repository:

```java
@Modifying
@Query(value="call proc(?1,?2,?3,?4,?5)",nativeQuery = true)
void saveProc(@Param("reply_by") Long replyBy,
              @Param("reply_to") Long replyTo,
              @Param("reply") String reply,
              @Param("status"),
              @Param("app_id") long appId);
```

As some of the parameter are `null` (foreign key).

ServiceImpl:

```java
repo.saveProc(2,null,"dvvf",null,null)  // java null
```

I'm getting this error:

> procedure proc(bigint, bytea, character varying,  bytea,bytea) does not exist
>
> Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

How can I pass `null` values instead of `bytea`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the parameter that could be null because Hibernate does not know the parameter type: `@Query(value="call proc(cast(?1 as bigint),cast(?2 as bigint),?3,cast(?4 as bigint),cast(?5 as bigint))",nativeQuery = true)`